# How to load Springboot application.properties, or application-profile.properties by passing in Properties objects at startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, properties-file

How to pass in spring boot application properties directly at startup instead of using application.properties/application-profile.properties files?

I'm going to lead in with a similar question later about XML bean configuration files via in memory Strings, StringBuilder, or other mechanisms.

Thanks for all ideas, suggestions that can answer my questions.

Aaron

I know how to use custom properties files with different annotations, but I'm attempting some property loading that isn't file system based, therefore we could consider the properties files I want to load properties documents which could be represented by the properties class in Java. Or in spring boot whatever their custom class implementation is that they use for properties. And possibly how to even override it, and use a custom properties file reader.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How to pass properties to the application at startup is quite clearly explained in the documentation. What isn't clear about that or didn't you simply read the documentation about [externalizing configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)? It is the command line properties, just pass them as arguments, you could even pass them as a JSON string. When using Spring Cloud Config or Spring Vault you even have more options.

Comment: @M. deinum I asked how to pass a property's object, I didn't ask how to load one from a file. Obviously I would like to use a custom properties file reader that I implement myself. Even the yaml reader converts the yaml into a key value pair properties file. I also alluded to the fact that I want to do the same thing with an Spring XML configuration bean XML file.

Comment: I suggest to read my comment again.. I nowhere state that you shoiuld load it from a file. You can simply pass arguments or a json structure.. I **nowhere** mentioned a file, so read again before you start accusing me of something I didn't say. If you want to implement your own go ahead, implement a `PropertySource` and use an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to register it (explained in aforemented documentation as well!). I don't really see what a Spring XML file has to do with it as that can be loaded with `@ImportResource`.

Comment: I am securing the application, I don't want an bad actor to be able to replace the application properties file in my application with their own text file to take over it. I don't want an internal bad actor with file system access to be able to read the configuration files, nor do I want to encrypt specific properties IE key value pair values, I want to encrypt the entire file so it cannot be modified or read. Therefore, I don't necessarily believe the external configuration properties documentation is adequate. A property source loads later on so that's not going to solve my app prop problem.